# Create NPM package from multiple angular2 components for a CRUD application

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-components

I am new to angular2 and I have successfully created three components for create/edit, view and listing employees and the component selectors are like `<create-employee>, <view-employee>, <list-employee>`.

My requirement is I need to create a single npm package in the nodejs library for public distribution of this employee module such a way that the single npm module should have all these three components available.

So far I did create an npm package for  with the help of this [documentation](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library). And I could install this as node modules in my application and successfully worked the create employee functionality. But what I am lacking is the other two components. Rather than create two other node packages for view and list I would like to make the three components available within a single npm package.

What I am expecting is :

```
app.module.ts

import { EmployeeModule } from 'employee-library';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [..],
  imports: [EmployeeModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })

user-create.component.html
  <create-employee></create-employee>

user-view.component.html
  <view-employee></view-employee>

user-list.component.html
  <list-employee></list-employee>
```

Comment: thank you for the valuable negative vote !!. Got my solution from below answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your 3 components in `EmployeeModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// import ... 3 modules

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CreateEmployee, ViewEmployee, ListEmployee ],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [...],
  exports: [ CreateEmployee, ViewEmployee, ListEmployee ]
})
export class EmployeeModule{ }
```

then public your library, after that, you could using your module

```
import { EmployeeModule } from 'employee-library';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [..],
  imports: [EmployeeModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{ }
```

> exports : Array|any[]> Specifies a list of
>   directives/pipes/modules that can be used within the template of any
>   component that is part of an Angular module that imports this Angular
>   module.

Document link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgModule-interface.html#!#exports-anchor

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!!. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hi friend !! Worked super.. Thanks a lot!!